# SQL multi order

Tags: php, sql

Assume this array is my db table.

```
array('1','1','1','2','2','2','3','3','3','4','4','4','4','5','5','5','5');
```

in that table i have status from 1 to 5. but i want get data first with status = 2,sec 5 ... ,1,3,4.

is it possible ? if not how can i do it with php.

Comment: And "array" is not a SQL data type (although it does exist in some databases).  What does the table look like?  Also, tables represent *unordered* sets.

Answer (score 2):

You may order using `FIELD`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY FIELD(status,2,5,1,3,4);
```

### Demo

Comment: ohh that is so good ,but i'm working with symfony 2.7 .and occouring any error. any idea for how to use ORDER BY FIELD in smyfony  ?

Comment: @KainMikayilli My answer should work as a raw query.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the array from a table then you could use a CASE WHEN in the ORDER BY of your query

For example:

```
select num 
from YourTable
order by (case when num = 2 then 1 when num = 5 then 2 else num+2 end);
```